# Answer appears as a float and I don't know why in python

Tags: python, variables

I am doing a programming project. It gives a user (aimed for primary school students) a randomly generated question. When I do my division code the answer is a real/float variable meaning that unless the user has a .0 at the end of a whole number, their answer is processed as incorrect. My code is:

```
while True:
            num1 = str((random.randint(0,12)))
            num2 = str((random.randint(0,12)))
            if num1 >= num2:
                question = (num1 + " " + "/" + " " + num2)
                print(question)
                answer = str((int(num1) / int(num2)))
                reply = str(input())
                if reply == answer:
                    score = score + 1
                    print("Correct")
                    break
                else:
                    print("Incorrect")
                    print("The answer was", answer)
                    break
            else:
                print("")
```

I understand that sometimes the answer will have a decimal point in it but is there a way of allowing a whole number to not have a .0 at the end. If not then how can I improve the code so I don't get this issue. Any help is appreciated. My python-idle version is 3.8

Comment: The editor you use to write code and the shell-equivalent you use to submit it to python are irrelevant to this and the other questions you are asking.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`/` is **float** division in Python. If you want to get an int with the line `answer = str((int(num1) / int(num2)))` then you should be using `//` instead, which is **integer** division.

Comment: Then how do I make it so that it so there is no questions where a decimal point would be included in the answer?

Comment: @PNX You should be converting the user input to an int or float as well if you want to compare it against your answer. That's why it's not working right now, because it's comparing the string ''X.0" to "X" and finding that they are different. You should use integer division if you are only expecting integers, but regardless, you should convert your string input into a float or an int before you compare it to a float or an int.